# Is []<typename>(){} a valid lambda definition?

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, clang, language-lawyer

I was experimenting with lambdas and compilers because of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39947881/4987285) here on SO.
I've just realized (and it's perfectly normal indeed) that the following code is valid:

```
int main() {
    auto l = [](){};
    l.operator()();
}
```

Actually the standard says that *the closure type has a public inline function call operator* and so on, thus it makes sense to be able to invoke it.

What I can't explain by looking at the standard (well, the working draft) is the fact that GCC (6.1) compiles the following snippet (clang 3.9 does not):

```
int main() {
    auto l = []<typename>(){};
    l.operator()<void>();
}
```

No warnings, no errors. Is it valid code or should it be rejected by the compiler?

Comment: [Compiled successfully](http://cpp.sh/4asuj)

Comment: @amanuel2 I know that it compiles (with GCC at least), but the question is if it's valid or not.

Comment: C++14 will allow "templated" lambdas, but that's with the `auto` keyword instead of the `<>` template syntax (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575901/can-lambda-functions-be-templated). Maybe the GCC developers wanted to experiment with different ways to add this kind of functionality?

Comment: @G.Sliepen You are speaking about generic lambdas and I know them. Here I'm actually asking something that is slightly different.

Comment: FWIW, I'm proposing to change this behavior in [P0428R0](https://github.com/ldionne/wg21/blob/master/generated/P0428R0.pdf). This will be part of the pre-Issaquah mailing.

Comment: @LouisDionne Interesting indeed. To be honest, the syntax is somehow ugly, but I see your reasons in the document.

Comment: @LouisDionne: You mention in your paper that this extension was implemented in GCC in 2009, could this explain why GCC accepts this code even though it is not standard and thus be worthy of an answer?

Comment: @G.Sliepen "C++14 will" - you mean _has_, for 2 years.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In N4140 5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda], a Lambda expression is defined as

> lambda-introducer lambda-declarator<sub>opt</sub> compound-statement

where a *"lambda-introducer"* is the `[]`, enclosing an optional *"lambda-capture"* and *"lambda-declarator<sub>opt</sub>"* is the stuff starting with *"( parameter-declaration-clause )"*.

```
[]<typename>(){}
```

does not meet that requirement because there is something between the lambda introducer and the lambda declarator, so it is not a valid lambda expression.

Thus, your example code is not valid C++ and should be rejected by the compiler.

---

As this is also tagged [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc), I clicked through the list of [GNU C++ extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html#C_002b_002b-Extensions). I did not find any extension that would make the syntax in question legal in GNU C++.

However, according to Section 4 of [this proposal](https://wg21.link/P0428R0) (P0428R0), which proposes to add templated lambdas to C++, gcc got an experimental implementation of the aforementioned paper in 2009. This probably explains why gcc doesn't complain here.

Comment: Given the question is flagged GCC, it is worth checking if there is a gnu extension to the standard in this respect.

Comment: @Vality Agreed, added. Thanks.

Comment: I've opened an issue to GCC, does it worth mentioning it too?

Comment: @skypjack If it adds information, like a dev confirming whether or not they consider it a bug, I think it would be helpful. Feel free to edit it in.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Ok, I'll see how it evolves and I'll edit it in if needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a GCC extension (templated lambdas).

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto l = []<typename T>(T const& x){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " " << x << std::endl;};
    l(42);
    l("Hello world");
}
```

results in

```
main()::<lambda(const T&)> [with T = int] 42
main()::<lambda(const T&)> [with T = char [12]] Hello world
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation of this? I've not been able to find it and that's why I excluded the possibility of being an extension. Thank you.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2009-08/msg00174.html is the closest I could find @skypjack

Answer (score 0):

The given code is well-formed and works as intended since C++20.

Per [[expr.prim.lambda]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda):

> *lambda-expression*: 
>      *lambda-introducer lambda-declarator<sub>opt</sub> compound-statement*
>       *lambda-introducer* `<`
>   *template-parameter-list* `>` *requires-clause<sub>opt</sub> lambda-declarator<sub>opt</sub> compound-statement*

The last line reflects this syntax.  Per [[expr.prim.lambda]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#5):

> A lambda is a *generic lambda* if there is a *decl-specifier* that is
>   a *placeholder-type-specifier* in the *decl-specifier-seq* of a
>   *parameter-declaration* of the *lambda-expression*, **or if the lambda has a *template-parameter-list*.**